# vQmod displays xml on top of the page after minor change in PHP code

Tags: php, xml, opencart, vqmod

All, please help

I am using OpenCart with vQmod and some OpenCart extension installed

Problem I am having is: if I make a small change in PHP file on the line that is not being modified/serched by vQmod, when displayed on screen, there will be some xml code dumped on top of the page. The xml dumped is actually a code that is being replaced somewhere else in the same PHP file were i made minor change.
Here is an screenshot where the code form vQmod xml is dumped on top of the page:
[image]

Interesting, that even, if i undo my change, the xml will still be dumped at the top of the page. To stop xml being dumped, i need to restore the PHP file from backup. 
I do understand what vQmod is doing, but why cant i change something in PHP code that vQmode is not searching or modifying? It will do this if i even add just an empty space at the bottom of the PHP file and then save it.

Any suggestions what could be wrong or not working?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here was the problem: the Encoding or more precisely NetBeans 7.4 Encoding
For developing I am using NetBeans 7.4 with UTF-8 page Encoding. When i save the file in NetBeans i got this error (xml dump at the top of the page).
Then added a blank space and saved the same document in Notepad++  with UTF-8 Encoding and problem fixed.

What i did was downloaded NetBeans 8 beta, that seems to work

Just an fyi.